# Cross domain web service call using jquery, web service is hosted on iis6.0

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery, iis-6

I am using this code for cross domain web service call :

$.support.cors = true;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: baseurl + "/HelloWorld",
    data: '{}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    }
});
```

I added this header entry in IIS6.0 : **Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"**

When I run it, i get 500 internal server error(Check in browser console).

Can anyone please let me know how to solve cross domain webservice access issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check your server logs. If there was indeed a 500 error your server should have an error message explaining what failed.

Comment: Why do you have dataType defined twice and you don't need a jsonCallback.  If you turn the dataType to jsonp, the cross-domain call shouldn't have any issues.  I regularly use 
    $.ajax({
url: 'Myurl', 
type: 'GET', 
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
dataType: 'jsonp', 
success: function(d) { //Do something}});`